# why do i get MethodError: objects of type Float64 are not callable?

Tags: julia

i have this function:

```
function prob(q, na, mask)
            q0 = round(Int, q.>0)
            m0 = round(Int, mask)
            return prod((q0 + (1-2q0).*pdet0(na)).^m0)
        end
```

where `pdet0()`is another function, when i want to call the function i see a `MethodError: objects of type Float64 are not callable`, apparently the error is in the last line of the function and it has something to do with placing the variable before a parenthesized expression but i really can't see it because it looks fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide all the information needed to run the function and reproduce the error. What is `q`, `na`, `mask`? What is `pdet0`?

Comment: the reason why i didn't post the entire code because it's a package built including more than one file, and the function that i posted here is basically a computation of the probability of detection of a photon `q` is the number of photons detected and `na`the number of arrived photons `mask`is the number of detectors so they are all numbers , here is the link of the entire file on `Github`:https://github.com/marouanehanhasse/Quantum_Relay/blob/master/src/QuantumRelay.jl

Answer (score 3):

As Kristoffer says, it's hard to say definitely given that your example doesn't run, but the culprit is most likely `pdet0(na)` which is interpreted as "call the function `pdet0` with the argument `na`.

In all likelihood, `pdet0` is a `Float64` number in your code, giving rise to the error. A minimum working example to reproduce the error would be:

```
julia> function1 = 1.0
1.0

julia> function1(5)
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Float64 are not callable
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1
```

You need to have a think about what `pdet0` is and why you're trying to call it. Do you by any chance come from Matlab and are trying to index into vector `pdet0`? This would be `pdet0[na]` in Julia, which will work if `pdet0` is a vector and `na` and Integer.

Comment: you are right but the thing is it was a confusion because i have a function named ith the same name of another variable, i didn't pay attention

Comment: but still, the `pdet0()`function is an intern function of another function in other file and when now i call the `prob()`i have the `UndefVarError: pdet0 not defined`, the `prob()`is inside a constructor .

Comment: That might well be a scoping issue, which unfortunately is nigh on impossible to debug remotely if you can't post a minimum working example of how you define `pdet0` and `prob` that reproduces the error...